# Email Validation function doesn't work | VB.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub btn_Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Submit.Click
    Dim _lblresponse As Label = Nothing
    _lblresponse = New Label

    Dim MyEmail As String = txb_Email.Text
    If EmailCheck(MyEmail) = True Then
        Dim _lblresponse_Valid As Label = Nothing
        _lblresponse = New Label
    Else
        Dim _lblresponse_Invalid As Label = Nothing
        _lblresponse = New Label
        _lblresponse.Text = "This is not a Valid Email"
        Me.plh_Response_Invalid.Controls.Add(_lblresponse)
    End If

    _lblresponse.Text = "*Your Request Has Been Sent"
    Me.plh_Response.Controls.Add(_lblresponse)




Function EmailCheck(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean


    Dim pattern As String = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
    Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailAddress, pattern)


    If emailAddressMatch.Success Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

The function says the email format is false but when the submit button is pressed. It will send the email as valid even though it is not. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. No need to use `emailAddressMatch`

```
If Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, pattern) then
  return true
Else
  return false
End If
```

Instead of

```
Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailAddress, pattern)
```

Comment: It now knows the email is not valid, as the correct labels are coming up whether it is 'true' or 'false'. but the submit button still works regardless and sends false emails

could this be to do with the submit button??